# Why is res.on('close') triggered two times?

Tags: node.js, http, web, server, backend

I have created a NodeJS HTTP Server with the HTTP built-in module.
When I use curl to request to the server, the "close" event is triggered only one time as I expected.
But when I use the browser, the "close" event is triggered two times.
Why does this happen?

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you comment out the console.log("closed"), will you still get one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've got the answer myself. I see that there is one more request from the browser to get favicon.ico.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).